# Positiong divs created by d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have four divs created by d3. I want 2 divs to appear on each row. I want to take into consideration the width and height of the divs. basically there will be 2 divs on a row and if one of the divs on a row has a certain height there should always be a  20px gap from that div's bottom to the div's that's below top. and I want there to be a 20px gap from the left of the first div to the right of the second div on the rows

I have data obj like this:

```
    var data = [
        {"name" : "alpha", "desc" : "This is Alpha"},
        {"name" : "Beta", "desc" : "This is Beta"},
        {"name" : "Gama", "desc" : "This is Gama"},
        {"name" : "Delta", "desc" : "This is Delta"},

    ]
```

I was hoping to make it something like this:

```
    {"name" : "alpha", "desc" : "This is Alpha", "top" : 0, "left"  : 0,"width" : 200, "height" : 300 },
    {"name" : "Beta", "desc" : "This is Beta", "top" : 0, "left"  : 220,"width" : 200, "height" : 300},
    {"name" : "Gama", "desc" : "This is Gama", "top" : 320, "left"  : 0,"width" : 250, "height" : 350},
    {"name" : "Delta", "desc" : "This is Delta", "top" : 320, "left"  : 270,"width" : 250, "height" : 350},
```

I'm trying to add the dimensions into the obj so I could easily use `.style` and plugin the appropriate values. something like this.`style("left", function(d){return d.left)`. If you have another solution I'll, be happy to here it. I'm willing to use jQuery .

My code that just shows the divs in the corner because of position absolute.

```js
var data = [
  {"name" : "alpha", "desc" : "This is Alpha"},
  {"name" : "Beta", "desc" : "This is Beta"},
  {"name" : "Gama", "desc" : "This is Gama"},
  {"name" : "Delta", "desc" : "This is Delta"}

]

  d3.selectAll("div.store")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .classed("store", true)
  .html( function(d){return "<h1 class = 'name'>"+ d.name + "</h1>  <p class = 'desc'>" + d.desc + "</p>"})
  .style("position" , "absolute")

  var dim = d3.selectAll("div.store")
  .node().getBoundingClientRect()

  console.log(dim.width)
```

```css
.name{
   color: steelblue;
  }
  .store {
   width  : 200px;
   border: 1px solid;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close to getting there. All you have to do is set the `top` and `left` style properties.

```js
var data = [
{"name": "alpha", "desc": "This is Alpha", "top": 0, "left": 0, "width": 200, "height": 300},
{"name": "Beta", "desc": "This is Beta", "top": 0, "left": 220, "width": 200, "height": 300},
{"name": "Gama", "desc": "This is Gama", "top": 320, "left": 0, "width": 250, "height": 350},
{"name": "Delta", "desc": "This is Delta", "top": 320, "left": 270, "width": 250, "height": 350}
];

d3.selectAll('div.store')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('div')
    .attr('class', 'store')
    .html(function(d) { return "<h1 class = 'name'>" + d.name + "</h1>  <p class = 'desc'>" + d.desc + "</p>"; })
    .style('position', 'absolute')
    .style('top', function(d) { return d.top + 'px'; })
    .style('left', function(d) { return d.left + 'px'; })
    .style('height', function(d) { return d.height + 'px'; })
    .style('width', function(d) { return d.width + 'px'; });
```

```css
.name {
color: steelblue;
}
.store {
border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's more complicated than this. you see you  put in fixed values. I put in fixed values in my question to give an example of  what I want the final result to look like. I can't add in fixed values because I don't know what the width and height are gonna be. The accepted answer would have to get the width and height and then apply the required formatting. Edit FYI I'm working on jQuery solution but if you could show a d3  way to do that, it would be better but any way would be accepted

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at this and was about to say replace your nested jquery eaches with d3's .each function, but then it occurred could you not just do this with css and do away with your left/top/absolute positioning in whatever library?

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/1761/ - edited to do the calc css rule for height too

```
body {
  background: #ffd;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  height: calc(50% - 10px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}

div:nth-child(2n) {
   margin-left: 20px;
 }

 div:nth-child(1),  div:nth-child(2) {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
```

Comment: I need the left, top, and absolute stuff. for example if the first div is 300 height and the second div is 100 height  the 3rd div would go fine under the first div but the fourth div will leave a gap between the second div and the fourth div. this usually happens when I use floats and that is why I decided to use `absolute`. will your solution work when the divs are different heights? would there be weird gaps? I'm not sure about `calc` . edit.. The height will made by the content

Comment: Ah. You'd have a further difficulty then. Say your first div is 300 x 300, and the second and third divs are 100 x 100, the fourth div - if it adjusts its top to the 3rd div and its left to the 2nd - would overlap the 1st (the diagonal)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I came up with the help of jQuery.

```js
var data = [
  {"name" : "alpha", "desc" : "This is Alpha" ,"text" : "<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam blanditiis saepe optio excepturi, amet ut, possimus nesciunt dolor sed magnam dolores eveniet, dignissimos commodi non autem facere voluptates esse sit.</p>"},
  {"name" : "Beta", "desc" : "This is Beta"},
  {"name" : "Gama", "desc" : "This is Gama"},
  {"name" : "Delta", "desc" : "This is Delta","text" : "<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam blanditiis saepe optio excepturi, amet ut, possimus nesciunt dolor sed magnam dolores eveniet, dignissimos commodi non autem facere voluptates esse sit.</p>"}

]

d3.selectAll("div.store")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .classed("store", true)
  .html( function(d){return "<h1 class = 'name'>"+ d.name + "</h1>  <p class = 'desc'>" + d.desc + "</p>"})
  .style("position" , "absolute")
.append("div")
.html(function(d){ return d.text})
$(function(){


  data.forEach(function(e, i, arr){
    ///first column
    if(i % 2 == 0){

      e.left = $("div.store").eq(i).offset().left
      if(i == 0){
        e.top = $("div.store").eq(i).offset().top 
        e.height = $("div.store").eq(i).outerHeight()
      }else{
        e.top = $("div.store").eq(i -2).outerHeight() + 20
      }


      console.log($("div.store").eq(i)) 
    }
    else if(i % 2 == 1 ){
      e.left = $("div.store").eq(i -1).outerWidth() + 20;
      if(i == 1){
        e.top = $("div.store").eq(i).offset().top;
      }
      else{
        e.top = $("div.store").eq(i -2).outerHeight() + 20;
      }
    }
  })

  d3.selectAll("div.store")
  .style("left", function(d) {return d.left + "px"})
  .style("top", function(d) {return d.top + "px"})



  console.dir(data)

})
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.name{
  color: steelblue;
}
.store {
  width  : 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
```